# EDB Replication Server, Sequences not updating

Tags: postgresql, replication, sequence

I'm using EDB Replication server to have 3 **postgres 14** databases in sync (MMR Replication).
I'm using Table Trigger as changeset logging
It's working fine for the most part, but I have a problem with Sequences.
Although the table rows change properly, the sequence is not updated on replicated tables.
I can update the Sequences manually, I use this code:

```
SELECT SETVAL(
    (SELECT PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE('"table"', 'id')),
    (SELECT (MAX("id") + 1) FROM "table"),
    FALSE);
```

and it all works fine after that, but it's a real hassle to run that code every time there is an addition on the database. And for each table affected.
Is there a way to update the Sequence during replication automatically?

Machines are all using Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [working as designed](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/eprs/latest/02_overview/04_design_replication_system/03_restrictions_on_replicated_database_objects/). In a multi-master replication setting sequences can be (and normally are) updated independently on each write node. To avoid conflicts consider using multimaster-ready sequences or other techniques described in the documentation.